# .Net: Is there a size limit on generic object list List(Of T)?

Tags: asp.net

Is there a limit on how many object a list can hold?

Comment: To be fair, if you're asking this question, you may have a design issue that needs to be addressed.  (This is almost always the case when questions about system limits are asked.)

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the count/item/etc property of the generic List (of T); it is an integer.

So i guess Integer.MaxValue (2147483647) is a good guess.

Answer (score 2):

There's an easy way to find out :-)

```
int count = 0;
while (true)
{
    myList.Add(new object());
    Console.WriteLine("added " + count++ + " objects");
}
```

Comment: Yep - if you run out of memory before "bad things" happen in code, then you can probably assume "no".

Answer (score 2):

The .Count property of a list is an integer, so it's somewhat limited in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

Only those imposed by your physical architecture, available memory etc...

Answer (score 0):

Please keep in mind that large collections might end up on Large Object Heap.  This part of managed memory doesn't get cleaned up as well as Gen0,1,2, so please proceed with caution.  Let the runtime select collection sizes based on the data that you actually need to add.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is limited to the amount of memory you have.  The more you add to the List, the more items are added to the stack until the reference is released and the garbage collector grabs it back.